# Drupal: template.php in theme, how can I edit the block back-end page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I use phptemplate_node_form in template.php to edit my back-end node pages

```
function phptemplate_node_form($form) {
```

Which is the function to edit the blocks instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to do block_preprocess in D7. But for now can you get by using the block.tpl.php file to customize the output?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--block.tpl.php/6

Comment: isn't block_preprocess only working for the front-end ? I'm actually talking of the back-end forms